# How to simulate a selection from a SELECT control in sfTestBrowser

Tags: testing, symfony1, functional-testing

In a functional test in symfony, sfTestBrowser provides methods

- click() "Simulates a click on a link or button."
- select() "Simulates selecting a checkbox or radiobutton."

and unselect().

But I have not found a way to simulate making a selection from a <select> element.

Does anybody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has troubled me too. I'm assuming you just want to set the value for form submission? If you know the value, you can of course just do

```
$browser->click('Save', array(
    'theselectfield' => 'desired_value'
));
```

But usually I don't know the value I want posted, because it's from a database-driven select box. So my solution is

```
$theOption = $browser->getResponseDomCssSelector()->matchAll('select[name*=name_of_select_field] option:contains(TheOptionTextYouWant)')->getNode();

$browser->setField('theselectfield', $theOption->getAttribute('value'));
... or use $browser->click() instead ...
```

Frustrating because you have to break out of the $browser call chain, in order to use getResponseDomCssSelector(), but I haven't found an easier way.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of something like that, but it looked horrendous, and I couldn't see how to select the option. If it's the transition I'm testing, browser->click() will work (though it's a pain to work out all the arguments).